# Reducing double summation to geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I reduce this summation to a geometric series?

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^{25i}\cdot\displaystyle\sum\limits_{j=i}^n x^{5j}$

I'm a little confused since the second summation begins at $i$.

Comment: Just a note on LaTeX, to make your future formulas shorter: If you are in display math mode, then you do not need the displaystyle macro. And even when you need it, you only need it once per formula. And in display style mode, the sum macro does not need the limit macro, since it puts automatically the index boundarys above and below.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the inner sum explicitly after noticing that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j = i}^n x^{5j} &= x^{5i}\sum_{j = 0}^{n - i}x^{5j} \\
&= x^{5i} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - i} (x^5)^j
\end{align*}

Once you've done this, a similar reindexing on the outer series will allow you to compute the entire sum.

Comment: ($n-i$) may be for the last expression. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Quite right; they look rather similar that small....